# checked in project file and branching

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, ide, intellij-idea

I have checked in my project settings to git. My question is what happens in the case when you have branches that might not have the most recent settings. It's almost as if you want the project file to be always off of "master". Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

We do branch when we want to work on sth. different on some point. When you finish the little job in the branch, you can merge it back to your dev branch and leave the branches there. I think keep the main dev branches as latest would be fine.